# R : similar operations on data files with similar names

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 10 `.dat` files that correspond to x-y values of 10 time steps. File names have this pattern : `tstepxx.dat`. For instance, `tstep01`, `tstep35`, `tstep55`, ... . `xx` do not follow any orders. I want to do the same operations on all files. I am looking for a way to not to repeat every operation 10 times. For instance, to read and name them, I have already tried :

```
n <- c(01, 35, 55, 78, 90, 120, 150, 175, 190, 215)
For (i in n) {
paste0("data+", i) <- read.table(file = sprintf("tstep%s.dat", i))
colnames(paste0("data+", i)) <- c("x","h")}
```

Or

```
for( n in i) {
paste0("data+", i) <- read.table(file = paste0("tstep",n,".dat"))
}
```

But none of them worked. What is the correct way of doing this ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot ussing `<-` like that. Instead check out `assign()`

Comment: Use a `list` and `lapply()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy! You can safe your files in one folder. Than list all files with your specific name with a regex and afterwards read all found files with the `purrr` package and the `map` function. The advantage of `map` is that you can pass arguments to the `read.table` function. Here is the example code:

```
# load libraries
library(purrr)

# list of file paths
files <- list.files(path="./input/.", pattern="tstep\\d{2}\\.dat", full.names=T)

# list of loaded data
data <- map(files, read.table)
```